# Make lists from pdf file in python

Tags: python, pdf, paragraph

I'm going to read a pdf file in python and make a data frame.
DataFrame = (Locality, Reference, Price...)
[image]
There are so many pages like this picture.
How can I do that?

I tried to solve this problem by using regular expression but I haven't done it.

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer

Using `borb` you can extract text from a PDF.
There are plenty of options:

- extract all text (left to right, top to bottom)
- extract text at a given location (using `LocationFilter`)
- extract text in a given `Color` (using `FontColorFilter`)
- extract text in a given `Font` (using `FontNameFilter`)

Furthermore, you can also write your own!
In your case, try to separate out those pieces of text that are unique, and map them to their meaning.

- For instance, the "owner" is always in dark blue, on an orange background, in a bold font, the text always starts with "Owner".
- The "reference" field is in dark blue, on a white background, bold font, and its text starts with "REF".
- etc

You can find an example of extracting text by color in [the examples repository](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#582-filtering-by-font_color).

I'll copy the entire example here for the sake of completeness.

```py
#!chapter_005/src/snippet_019.py
import typing
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.toolkit import FontColorFilter
from borb.toolkit import SimpleTextExtraction
from borb.pdf import X11Color

from decimal import Decimal


def main():

    # create FontColorFilter
    # the constructor accepts 2 arguments; the color to filter on, and the "distance" (this is a measure of how much a color is allowed to be different from that target color). By playing around with the distance, you'll be able to do things like "get me all text that is "somewhat" like this color
    l0: FontColorFilter = FontColorFilter(X11Color("Red"), Decimal(0.01))

    # filtered text just gets passed to SimpleTextExtraction
    l1: SimpleTextExtraction = SimpleTextExtraction()
    l0.add_listener(l1)

    # read the Document
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle, [l0])

    # check whether we have read a Document
    assert doc is not None

    # print the names of the Fonts
    print(l1.get_text_for_page(0))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```